# nginx websocket proxy: using defined location

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I'm trying to [setup websocket proxy](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/) for a defined location (`/ws`) and it doesn't work. But using root (`/`) as location works for me.

works:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://echo.websocket.org;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
}
```

doesn't work:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /ws {
        proxy_pass http://echo.websocket.org;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
}
```

I also inspected the server response:

```
curl -i -N -H "Connection: Upgrade" -H "Upgrade: websocket" -H "Host: localhost:8888" -H "Origin: http://localhost:8888/ws" http://localhost:8888/ws

HTTP/1.1 404 WebSocket Upgrade Failure
Server: nginx/1.13.12
Date: Thu, 17 Jan 2019 15:15:50 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 77
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-websocket-extensions
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-websocket-version
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: x-websocket-protocol
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:8888/ws

<html><head></head><body><h1>404 WebSocket Upgrade Failure</h1></body></html>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is with the pattern matching. You first have to give websocket url from client side as **ws://localhost:80/ws/** 
Note here you have to give (**/**) at the end of the url, and at the NGINX server side, configure it in this way :

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  localhost;

location /ws/ {
    proxy_pass http://echo.websocket.org;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_buffering off;
}}
```

Note here that you have to give **/ws/** reference to location.